# excercise, the continuous function space

Tags: real-analysis

I have this excercise:
I hve solved a and b, but I am stuck on c:

[image]

What I tried is this:

Since the function takes values in $\mathbb{R}^m$, and the interval is compact, I know the function bounded(extreme value theorem), so I know that $d_Y(f(u),f(v))=|f(u)-f(v)|\le|f(u)|+|f(v)|\le2*K$. So if I choose the function $2*K*d_X(x,y)$, I will be ok if the distance is 0, or bigger or equal to 1. But in the interval (0,1) it might fail. Is it a way to fix this?